# How to delete rows based on some specific values of a dataframe column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe '`df`' which has a column '`var`'.

This column has various values, for example `medium,large,my (gold),light (silver)` etc.

Now I need to remove rows from this dataframe which have values either `(gold)` or `(silver)` in '`var`' column.

I have tried with this:

```
df = df[df['var'] != '(silver)']
df = df[df['var'] != '(gold)']
```

But it's not working because column has not exact value as (silver) or (gold). Instead these values are part of some string.

Please suggest how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use can [`pd.str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) with `re.escape`:

```
import re

query = '|'.join([re.escape(i) for i in ['(gold)', '(silver)']])

df = df[~df['var'].str.contains(query)]
```

Comment: @AnalyticsPy, Sorry, check now.